# How can I return an integer that indicates the number of distinct sub-strings that are palindrome?

Tags: java

Can anyone help me with my code? Because I do not understand what I am doing wrong. Thank you!

Here below is my code:

```
public class Solution{

//code I need Help with:

public static int palindromeCount(String s) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)) {
            }
            count++;
        }
        break;
    }

    return count;
}

//Given and can't change:

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    final String fileName = System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH");
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    if (fileName != null) {
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
    } else {
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
    }

    int res;
    String s;
    try {
        s = in.nextLine();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        s = null;
    }

    res = palindromeCount(s);
    bw.write(String.valueOf(res));
    bw.newLine();

    bw.close();
    }
  }
```

Output:
Your function must return an integer denoting the number of distinct sub-strings of s are palindromes.

Ex Input:

s = aabaa

Output:

5

Reason: a, aa, aabaa, aba, b

The sub-string ‘a’ occurs 4 times, but we are looking for distinct sub-strings. Then it is counted only once. Similarly, the string ‘aa’ occurs twice but counts as one distinct palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an int count you could add each of the the strings into a Set (which can't contain duplicates) and the at the end of the function just return the Set's size.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Comment: hmm I did try that, but I didn't know how to implement it.

Comment: @R.. You would need a double nested for loop - one for length of string, and another for going down the string... basically `for(length of potential substring starting length 1 and ending length of this string) { for(each potential starting character of the string) { String potential = s.substring(...); if(isPalindrome(potential)) set.add(potential); } } return potential.size();` - in a nutshell

Comment: @corsiKa I did try that before I did this code and that was not working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of how to use a Set to eliminate duplicates.

```
import java.util.*; //Needed import to use the Set

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String s = "aabaa";  //Test String - Has 5 palindroms: a, aa, aabaa, aba, b 
    HashSet<String> countSet = new HashSet<String>();  //Use a Set since it will elimate duplicate values
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) { 
        for (int j = i+1; j <= s.length(); j++) {  //check every substring possibility
            if(isPalindrom( s.substring(i,j).toCharArray() ) ) //If the substring is a palindrom...
            {
              countSet.add(s.substring(i,j)); //... add it to our Set.  Duplicates will be ignored because it is a Set
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("HERE: " + countSet.size());  //The number of palindroms.  5 in this case
  }

  //Fuction that checks if a char[] is a palindrom
  public static boolean isPalindrom(char[] word){
    int i1 = 0;
    int i2 = word.length - 1;
    while (i2 > i1) {
        if (word[i1] != word[i2]) {
            return false;
        }
        ++i1;
        --i2;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!!